# Re-Select Previous Visual Selection with Command

Tags: vimscript

As title. I want to create a function that facilitate this behaviour. I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
exe 'gv'
```

I tried from this direction because this works:

```
exe 'c!'
```

Comment: @mattb: Yes, exactly. Title updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run normal mode commands as ex command use `:normal!` as in

```
   normal! gv
```

Note, exclamation mark is for running non-mapped "built-in" functionality:

```
:nnoremap l :echo "hello"<CR>
" this would echo hello
:normal l
" this would move cursor right
:normal! l
```